# number in string to find char in that string UNIX

Tags: unix, sed

I have a string that contains a word and a number, like this:

```
"6 ovenbread"
```

How can I read the number (let's call it `i`) and find the `i`th character of the word?

It seems that `s/([0-9]) (.){\1}/\2/` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think awk is easier, it has `substr` function, allows you to pick the n-th letter.

```
awk '{print substr($2,$1,1)}'
```

with your data:

```
kent$ echo "6 ovenbread"|awk '{print substr($2,$1,1)}'
r
```

Comment: would you also happen to know how i can now remove this char from the string?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that in `sed`, but it's easy enough in Awk.

```
awk '{ print substr($2,$1,1) }' file
```

Comment: would you also happen to know how i can now remove this char from the string?

Comment: `$2 = substr($2,1,$1-1) substr($2, $1+1)`